# Создание экземпляра generic класса с помощью рефлексии

Tags: java, рефлексия

есть  такой класс

```
public class MyClass<T extends Entity> {}
```

Каким образом можно создать типизированы экземпляр такого класса, с помощью `Class.forName` или каким либо другом образом,  если мне изначально известно имя `MyClass` и имя класса `T` ?

Comment: в справке есть [пример](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/ctorInstance.html)

Comment: Можете привести пример кода о котором вы говорите в ответ?

Comment: не, лучше сначала добавь в вопрос чуть больше информации. Возможно я не совсем понял что именно у тебя есть на входе и что конкретно ты хочешь получить в итоге

Comment: Добавил, в результате я хочу получить экземпляр класса с generic-ом  нужного мне типа

Answer (score 1):

Создание экземпляра параметра в `java` запрещено ввиду того, что обобщения (`generic`) в `java` реализованы с помощью механизма [`type erasure`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). Из-за данной реализации во время выполнения программы тип параметра заменяется на `Object` или тип, указанный как ограничивающий (bound) тип параметра. То есть в случае, если указано `class MyClass<T extends Entity>`, то после компиляции `T` везде заменяется на `Entity`, а где нужен типизированный объект, используется явное приведения типов вида: `SpecificEntity ent = (SpecificEntity)entetyObj;`.

Таким образом, по-хорошему в случае, когда необходимо создавать экземпляры объекта параметра, то следует создавать подтип обобщения с параметром конкретного типа, например вот так:

```
public class MyClass<T>{}

public class MyClass2 extends MyClass<String>{

  public String get() {
      return new String("test");
  }
}
```

---

Для случая, если обобщенный тип указан с ограничением (bound), можно создавать экземпляры классов самой "границы" или наследников этого класса (границы) без использования рефлексии. В коде необходимо выполнять явное преобразование типов к типу параметра, например вот так:

```
public class MyClass<T extends CharSequence>{
  public T get() {
     return (T) new String("test");
  }
}
```

**Но в этом случае вы создаете код, который заведомо работает с ошибками.** В случае использования класса с любым типом, не являющимся типом, который вы создаете явно, вы будете получать ошибку времени выполнения ClassCastException.

В случае примера выше: для `T extends CharSequence` любой наследник CharSequence, не являющийся типом `String`, например `StringBuffer`, будет вызывать `ClassCastException`.

```
MyClass<StringBuffer> c = new MyClass<StringBuffer>();
c.get().append(" второй test");  
/*компилятор не видит проблемы
   и считает, что мы получаем тип StringBuffer, 
   но во время выполнения получим ошибку:
   java.lang.ClassCastException:  
       java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.StringBuffer
*/
```

**В результате теряется смысл использования обобщения - компилятор теперь не может проверить правильность использования типов и предупредить вас об ошибке на этапе компиляции.**

Comment: Зачем вы привели второй пример? Это ведь небезопасный код - если кто-то использует `StringBuffer sb = new MyClass<StringBuffer>().get();`, то получит `ClassCastException`.

Comment: @Roman, Вы, правы, исправлю ответ - укажу, что это не безопасный вариант, и что он портит саму идею использования обобщения.